# Proper idiomatic way to implement clone method in Python class?

Tags: python, clone

How to idiomatically correct implement `clone` method in Python? See:

```
def clone(self):
    """
    Return a clone of this class
    """
```

Reason for `clone` - to construct identical class instance from usage point of view so internal state of copy may be changed without effecting original object.

To be concrete: constructor may initialize private fields which are primitive types or complex types:

```
def __init__(self, initial = None, width = DEFAULT_SIZE, height = DEFAULT_SIZE):
    self._width = width
    self._height = height
    self._matrix = ...complex code, list of list...
```

With primitive types - nothing hard. What to do with complex types?

If complex type is build-in like `tuple`, `set`, `dict` - there is `copy.copy` / `copy.deepcopy` package but I am unsure how usual it usage.

For complex types that foreign classes I don't know what to do.

***(1)*** Are any helpers to make copy easy? Or conventions so I can relay on them?

When I copy object I see no reason to use provided constructors, because I already have known all internal contracts and able to manipulate of internal state privately?

***(2)*** How I can instantiate object of same type without using constructor?

**UPDATE** I am taking *Principles of Computing* Coursera class and implement class that hidden by teaching stuff (for scoring reason).

They use `clone` in provided "interface". I am not experienced in Python classes so ask to proper way to deal in situation.

Comment: @kindall Official docs say: `copy.deepcopy`  *letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set of components copied*. That API supposed to be implemented by class?

Comment: "In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`."

Comment: Yes, exactly. Implement their API so users can use the standard module to make copies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either implement `__deepcopy__` (and/or `__copy__`) to provide direct support to [the `copy` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) APIs, or register a `pickle`-ing function with [`copyreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#module-copyreg); `copy.deepcopy` will use `copyreg` registered method to implement deepcopying if no `__deepcopy__` is defined.

Note that many Python types (e.g. `dict`, `list`, etc.) also provide a method named `copy` that performs a shallow copy; it's easy to support both idioms by assigning one name to the other, e.g.:

```
class Foo:
    def copy(self):
        ... do stuff to make a copy ...
        return newcopy
    __copy__ = copy  # Now works with copy.copy too
```